# Exec python script from PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

I'm trying to run a Python script from my Codeigniter app using exec(), like this:

```
exec('python script.py -a arg1 -b arg2');
```

but it's not working.
I have checked the file permissions, and the script runs just fine if I try to run it on my console.

If I add

```
exec('python script.py -a arg1 -b arg2', $output, $response);
```

`$output` comes out as `Array()` and `$response` as `1`.

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: You say you checked file permissions, however the user who is executing the web application (usually www-data in apache/nginx) will need to own this script as either the owner or group, unless you have permissions set to 777 which would allow all users to execute, but that is not advised.

Comment: The owner of the file is the user 'http' (the apache user in Arch linux).